Flutter (dart) and Stripe. Is it safe to run https from device to get intent?
A simple question. I am adding Stripe to my flutter app. It is working for both Android and iPhone, but I was wondering, is it safe sending sending request with Id and amount as header to Stripe with HTTPS? Can it be fetched by the user?
I am basicly doing this, how easy is it to get access to the secret key and modify the amount from the device?
`
Map<String, dynamic> body = {
'amount': calculateAmount(amount),
'currency': currency,
'description': kommentar,
  };

  //Make post request to Stripe
  var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents'),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${secretKey}',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: body,
  );

`
I am wondering adding this functionality to my Supabase edge function, but havent figure out how to do it yet, and if this is safe enough.

You should create a service on your backend and only call payment_intents from there. Your frontend can then call that backend. (The secret key is therefore not compiled into your front end code, but secure in your back end.

Thank you Richard, you are of course right :)
